# Capybara how to check if 'li' of a given link has proper css class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, capybara

Hi I have an nav like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li  >
          <a href="/">Strona Główna</a>
        </li>
        <li  class="active"  >
          <a href="/legendopedia">Legendopedia</a>
        </li>
        <li  ><a href="/pages/web_scrolls">Zwoje z Sieci</a></li>
        <li  >
            <a href="/users/sign_in">Zaloguj się</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/users/sign_up">Zarejestruj się</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

And I want to check with CAPYBARA if the 'li' that containts '/legendopedia' link has css class: active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there can be only one active li in the .container div you can do it like

```
expect(page.find('div.container li.active')).to have_selector(:link, '', href: '/legendopedia')
```

which is a little backward from what you mentioned since it's checking that the li with class active has the link with the relevant href in it, but is effectively the same.

Another way would be to use xpath

```
expect(page).to have_xpath("//li[.//a[@href='/legendopedia']][@class='active']")
```

Comment: The first returns me an error: `Unable to find css "div.conatiner li.active"`, but the second works fine. In the end I had figure it that it needs to be done this way, I went home and bang! your answer. Many thanks :)

Comment: Looks like I misspelled container in the first example it should work too